# ASP.NET MVC 5 using Jquery datepicker, not displaying time, preserving culture

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datepicker, asp.net-mvc-5

In a partial view, I do the following:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=> m.DateFrom, new{@class="datepicker"})
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=> m.DateTo, new{@class="datepicker"})
```

This is the datepicker, defined in the main view:

```
@section scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $('.datepicker').datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            minDate: "-99Y",
            dateFormat: "@CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern.Replace("yyyy", "yy").ToLower()"
        });
    </script>   

}
```

This has two problems:

1) The two datepickers both default to 0001-01-01 00:00:00
2) They display the time, as shown above.

I think I can solve #1 by doing something like:

```
[Display(Name = "MyOrdersControl_From", ResourceType = typeof (SiteTextResources))]
public DateTime DateFrom
        {
            get { return _dateFrom.HasValue ? _dateFrom.Value : new DateTime(1970, 1, 1); }
            set { _dateFrom  = value; }
        }

private DateTime? _dateFrom;
```

But when I look for solutions to removing time, I see things such as adding

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-mm-dd}")]
```

But not only does this not remove the time, it also overrides my culture sensitive dateformating (I think?). I have seen suggestions to change the TextBoxFor to EditorFor, which indeed fixes the time issue, but does to lose the datepicker binding. As well as having that same culture problem.

What to do?

Comment: The datepicker has a format property that you can use like this  `datepicker({ format: 'dd.mm.yyyy' })`

Comment: I am already using the format property. Along with CultureInfo. Are you saying I shouldn't?

Answer (score 0):

Add format like this:

```
dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy'
```

And this into web.config:

```
<globalization culture="en-US" uiCulture="en-US" />
```

Comment: Thanks, but the culture is supposed to still depend on who's logged on.

Comment: Okay, so, you should look for dateFormat, I think. try: 'dd-mm-yy', 'yy-mm-dd' and so on.